# Is a polyhedron with different prime length edges possible?

Tags: geometry

Can a polyhedron be constructed  with all its  edges of different prime number length ? A primahedron maybe ? Is there a limit or constraint on the number of such polyhedra, similar to the limit of 5 Platonic regular solids?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Comment: A tetrahedron can be easily formed if the $6$ prime numbers chosen satisfy the triangle inequality on each of the $4$ triangular faces.

Comment: Good point player3236. I have edited my question bit.

Answer (score 4):

1. For the elementary case of a tetrahedron, the smallest one you can consider is:

$$3,5,7,11,13,17$$

In this [reference](http://www.rimwe.com/the-solver-blog/80.html), you will find its folding pattern:

[image]

In fact, many others can be constructed (maybe an infinity of them), for example:

$$13, 17, 19,23,29,31$$

Indeed, considering triangle with sides $13,17,19$ as the base triangle, strict triangle inequalities are valid for the 3 other facets:

$$(13,23,27), \ \ (17,27,31), \ \ (19,31,23)$$

2. The farthest you take, in the table of primes, $6$ consecutive primes, the more "almost-equilateral" the facets will be , with a guarantee that all triangle inequalities are checked...
3. The case of a hexahedron (volume with six faces): build two tetrahedra in the manner seen above with the same base, then glue them on this common base.
4. This "gluing" method could be extended to more general polyhedra (with the possibility that the generated polyhedron isn't convex).
5. About "stacked polyhedra", in particular stacked (or glued) tetrahedra, see [here](https://mathoverflow.net/q/357795).

Comment: Nice response and reference Jean Marie thanks